# How to paint colours over a background image?

Tags: android

I've been asked to create an app that allows the user to fill in areas of an image with different colours, very similar to a childs "colour by numbers" game. 
I'm not sure how to delineate the areas of the image and make them selectable. Please could someone give me an idea of a good way to go about doing this in Android.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of a tricky task... There's probably a better way to implement it, but here's my first thought:

You could pre-break the image into separate segments before the app runs.

As far as I know the only type of View you can create is a rectangle. But you can create many small rectangles to fill in parts of your image. Then you can get the clicks on those little areas and make a corresponding segment of your image:

```
int color= res.getColor(R.color.my_color);
image.setColorFilter(color, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ole. There are some pretty complex polygons in this so I hope theres a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing some NDK code, you could try OpenCV's [cvFloodFill](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=cvfloodfill#cvFloodFill) method. Otherwise you have to implement one of the [image segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) methods.